# How to use the result of a query to update another table?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a `Parent` table with many `Child`, and each `Child` have a `create_date`.

I now need to add a new column create_date for Parent, and find the `MIN(Child.create_date)` to be used for the `Parent.create_date`.

I can get the `MIN` `create_date`:

```
SELECT MIN(Child.create_date) FROM Child LEFT JOIN Parent USING(Parent.id) GROUP BY Parent.id
```

But how do I use the result to update the `Parent.create_date`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join` with `update` statement

```
UPDATE Parent p,
  (SELECT parent.id AS id, MIN(Child.create_date) AS new_date
  FROM Child LEFT JOIN Parent 
  ON Parent.id = Child.parent_id
  GROUP BY Parent.id
  ) AS my_table
SET p.create_date = my_table.new_date
WHERE p.id = my_table.id;
```

Comment: Why use an outer join? And mixing join syntax is a recipe for disaster!